# How to create user-functions with igraph in R?

Tags: r, function, colors, nodes, igraph

I'm trying to write a user-function using `igraph` indexing functions like `V(graph)$some_attribute`. Specifically, I'm trying to create a function that assigns a color ramp to an `igraph` `vertex.attribute` that is already stored in the graph.  I've got some code that specifies the basic idea and where I'm stuck.

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100,.01211)

V(g)$att <- sample(c(1:100),vcount(g),T)


sky_tom <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,'RdYlBu')) #color ramp

a <- sky_tom(100)[V(g)$att[order(match(V(g)$att,V(g)))]] # core of function
```

This bit, `sky_tom(100)[V(g)$att[order(match(V(g)$att,V(g)))]]`, ensures that the color from `sky_tom` is in an ascending order when plotted, otherwise the color wouldn't make sense.

```
set.seed(1)

par(bg = 'black',mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot.igraph(g,
     vertex.color = adjustcolor(a,.9),
     edge.color = adjustcolor('skyblue',.25),
     vertex.label = NA,
     vertex.size = 5,
     edge.curve = T,
     layout = layout.kamada.kawai(g))
```

[image: Plot with colorramp working]

My issue is getting this in a user-defined function. I get errors or NA's. Thanks very much.

```
function(x,y){
sky_tom(n_distinct(x)[y[order(match(y,x))]]
```